# How do I get a YouTube video title from a YouTube URL in Node.Js

Tags: node.js, discord, ytdl

I need to get a video title from a YouTube URL, I have no clue how to do it. I have asked on two discord support servers. I have got this code so far (i am also using YTDL-CORE)

```
const TEST = ytdl.getInfo('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YQHsXMglC9A', function (err, info) {
    console.log(info.videoDetails.title) // "Adele - Hello"
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The promising is not going to the desired function hence not printing the title. You should do something like this and voila.

```
ytdl.getInfo('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YQHsXMglC9A').then(info => {
    console.log(info.videoDetails.title);
})
```

> Adele - Hello